# How to demonstrate total internal reflection?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

How can we demonstrate [total internal reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection) practically to explain it clearly?

Comment: Here is a nice demo which is pretty cheap to set up with some laser pointers and a fish tank: http://video.mit.edu/watch/mit-physics-demo-refraction-a-total-internal-reflection-12044/

Comment: A ~4 cm circular rod of clear plastic and a HeNe laser (laser pointer ought to work too) was what we used when I TA'ed an optics lab.

Comment: Are you asking for something like an in-class demonstration?  I'm not clear on what you are looking for.

Comment: Similar to ThePhoton,  a thick half-disc of glass or clear plastic is good.  This, by analogy with a protractor, makes it easy to measure the TIR angle as well.  Set the disc up to rotate about the center of the full circle, aim the laser thru the curved side straight at the center, and see when the output thru the  flat side stops.

Comment: I've also seen it done with a laser, a length of fiber optic cable and a fish tank. My take on this is that we are looking at a make-a-list question with a *very* large number of correct answers. This would be better taken to chat or to slant.co.